# Fatal error with paypal payment

Tags: error, paypal, payment-gateway

I have a big problem with paypal on my shop. If i choose authorization on payment action, no problem, i can make an order, and paid on payla. I see my order on BO it's all great.

But i want to change for Sale method on payment action. If i choose this method, just after paid on paypal i am redirected on `http://mywebsite.com/paypal/express/return/?token=EC-xxxxxxxxxxxx&PayerID=xxxx` with the fallowing error :

> Fatal error: Call to a member function isDummy() on a non-object in
>   /srv/d_monexpresso/http/monexpresso/www/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Invoice/Total/Subtotal.php
>   on line 49.

If you could help me please.

Answer (score 1):

As you can see in the code:

```
public function collect(Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Invoice $invoice)
{
    // ...

    $order = $invoice->getOrder();

    foreach ($invoice->getAllItems() as $item) {
        if ($item->getOrderItem()->isDummy()) {
```

the method tries to loop over all order items based on the invoice item. For some reason there is no order item attached to the invoice item.

If I understand you correctly you go to the checkout, pay with paypal, then go back to the payment step and try to change the payment method (after already paid). I have no clue why this should be possible (but I understand it is, although it shouldn't), but I have no clue, why this method should be called during checkout.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the reply, in fact, what i'm doing is just activate "Sale" in payment action (configuration paypal), then i make an order, go to paypal, paid and then, paypal is redirect me in this blank page with this error.

I chek the file and you have right, the method loop over all items, but in this case they are no information about items.

If i choose the "Authorization" in payment action, i have no problem, i can make a complete order.

Thanks to help me.